# Neo4j - Relationship Clause and Degrees of Separation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Cypher query which works as I expected....

```
MATCH (n1 {id: "25fd62e4-9566-4cbd-a443-b2b8d739d6f4"})-[r]-(n2)
WHERE r.hierarchy IN ['Ge', 'H']
RETURN n1, r, n2
```

I'd like to add degrees of separation to this query.

This works

```
MATCH (n1 {id: "25fd62e4-9566-4cbd-a443-b2b8d739d6f4"})-[r*1..4]-(n2)
RETURN n1, r, n2
```

....but adding in the WHERE clause does not:

```
MATCH (n1 {id: "25fd62e4-9566-4cbd-a443-b2b8d739d6f4"})-[r*1..4]-(n2)
WHERE r.hierarchy IN ['Ge', 'H']
RETURN n1, r, n2
```

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of **variable-length-path patterns (your last query)**, a variable **`r`** is a collection of relationships and not a single relationship.

You can't check hierarchy for all the relationships in the collection with a single condition, you need to check the `hierarchy` for each of these with `WHERE` and `ALL` combined.

```
MATCH (n1 {id: "25fd62e4-9566-4cbd-a443-b2b8d739d6f4"})-[rels*1..4]-(n2)
WHERE ALL(r in rels WHERE r.hierarchy IN ['Ge', 'H'])
RETURN n1, rels, n2
```